# How decrease the size of images which are present in uploads folder?

Tags: images

I want to resize images in uploads folder. What would be the best way to resize images on a live website?

Comment: use a plugin
something like this https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/optimize-images-resizing/ Edited after @marks comment:
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/

Comment: @kaiser: Its a live client website. I can delete the current image and upload a new one in its place but that wouldn't be a good strategy.

Comment: @LuckyChingi, the problem with ewww is that it requires server side configuration, installing modules that might not be there by default, but yes that is a better plugin for this

Comment: @MarkKaplun time to create a new plugin for this request ;)

Comment: @FahadUddin, anything yet?

Comment: @prosti: Yes. Will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First I must say I like the web server approach where you create cron jobs.
In Linux, you have great options.

EXIF tool to remove bad meta information.
You just need to set the cron job once a day.

Since you need to optimize the existing images.

- For `png` images you have `optipng`
- For `jpeg/jpg` you have `jpegtran`

---

To regenerate the thumbnails from your images you can use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). You can find the author in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/107/viper007bond) in WPSO.

Just let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had limited access to the site, the best way to do it was to use a plugin. I used [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/) plugin's free version to compress all of the images on the site. It took me a few hours to click on the button to keep compressing the images.